# What is the difference between below two methods in c++

Tags: c++, object, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

```
MyClass* po = new MyClass();    
po->DoSomething();
```

and

```
MyClass po;    
MyClass* pp = &po;    
pp->DoSomething();
```

can you explain this including what'll happen in the stack and the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first case is creating using dynamic memory allocation from the heap an instance of type MyClass.  When you leave scope, the object pointed to po will still exist in the heap and leave a memory leak if not taken into account.

The second is instantiating an instance of MyClass on the stack.  Then you create a pointer to type MyClass pointing to the object on the stack.  When you leave scope, po will be destructed and the object pointed to by pp will be invalid.

Comment: What did you mean by leaving scope?

Comment: @malit.tilak If you declare a variable locally inside a function, the scope of the variable is that function. Once the function returns the scope ends and the variable will cease to exist. It's a little bit more complicated than that, since scopes can be nested, and structures, classes and namespaces introduce their own scope as well.

Comment: I would like to point out that C++'s `new` allocates memory on the **free store** while C-style `malloc` allocates memory on the **heap**. They are handled by separate memory managers, which is why you shouldn't mix `new` and `delete` with `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: Put things on the stack that are small (so you do not exhaust your stack) and temporary - these are your local variables in the function for example.  You want those either on the stack or on the registers in the CPU such as an iterator, the pointer itself pointing to the heap or a small buffer workspace that you want to reduce page switching on by the cpu memory manager.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeHoupis I got the idea very well.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the way you allocate memory.

1. `MyClass* po = new MyClass();` allocates memory from heap and returns the pointer. You can access the memory using the given pointer.
2. `MyClass po;` allocates the memory on stack. After you leave the scope (when the function returns) you can't access this memory even if you had the pointer.